# Algorithm for Ticket Reservation with multiple drop off points, destinations using rails and mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, algorithm, elasticsearch, graph-algorithm

I am running a reservation service with simple one to one origin and destination. As my service is growing I am considering to implement a multiple drop off points, destinations as below

A------>B----->C----->D

let's say a trip from A (origin) to D (destination) pass by B and C during it's journey.

My user can reserve a seat from A->B, A->C, A->D, B->C, B->D, and C->D. My problem is to find a good algorithm for seat availability given a question from 
B->D for example.

I came up with a simple solution as below

```
Routes:
-------------
id orig dest  seats   many_drop_off_points   desc               
1   A    D     40     yes                   multiple drop-offs
2   A    H     20     no                    straight
3   B    H     12     no                    straight
4   A    D     12     no                    straight
```

I have a Routes table which contains origin, destination. For simplicity I just put the total number of seats for that route.

The Routes table can have one or more Routings as below

```
Routhings
-----------------
id orig dest route_id  denormalize_seats
1   A    B      1          40
2   B    C      1          40
3   C    D      1          40
4   A    H      2          20
```

Routing belongs to a specific route. Routing can have many Reservation on a specific date.

```
RoutingReservation
---------------------------------
id  routing_id  date  customer_id
```

When setting up a route from A->D by passing through B and C.

```
 create in Routings table three record as shown in the table above(A->B, B->C, C->D).
```

In case from A->H straight without passing any place.
     create in Routing table a record (A->H)

When customer wanna search for a route from C->D I simply search from Route or Routings (**complicate calculation**)

Reserve seats is also **complicated**.

Reserve 10 seats from A -> D using Route 1 (multiple drop off point)

```
 Create 10 reservations for Routing 1 (from A->B)
 Create 10 reservations for Routing 2 (from B->C)
 Create 10 reservations for Routing 3 (from C->D)
```

Reserve 5 seats from A -> C

```
 Create 5 reservations from Routing 1 (from A->B)
 Create 5 reservations from Routing 2 (from B->C)
```

Reserve 10 seats from B -> D

```
  Create 10 seats from Routing 2 (from B->C)
  Create 10 seats from Routing 3 (from C->D)
```

To count the total number of reservation for a Routing from the 3 steps above (**complex calculation**)

```
  Routing 1 (from A->B) 10 + 5
  Routing 2 (from B->C) 10 + 5 + 10
  Routing 3 (from C->D) 10 + 10
```

Available seats from A->D routes

```
  Total - Max(total number of reservation) from A->B, B->C, C->D

  40 - Max(15, 25, 20) = 15  # Route with id 1
  20 - 0  = 0   # Route with id 4
```

Available seats from A->C routes

```
  Total - Max(total number of reservation) from A->B, B->C
  40 - Max(15, 25) = 15
```

Available seats from B->D

```
  Total - Max(total number of reservation) from B->C, C->D
  40 - Max(25, 20) = 15 # Route with id 1
```

Available seats from C->D

```
   Total - Max(total number of reservation) from C->D
   40 - Max(20) = 20  # Route with id 1
```

It seems like this kind of multiple drop off points can be implemented but with **lots of calculation**, currently I am having more than 30 partners with more than a thousand of Route but I would like to introduce this multiple drop-off points to couple of partners as my starting point.

I am looking an algorithm that can solve this problem more efficiently. My current environment is in **rubyonrails** and **mysql**.

Thanks for your help in advance.

ps: I am also open for other kind of data store like elasticsearch or mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to be easiest if you consider *all* routes as having many drop-off points, and just view the simple routes (A->B, B->C) as the trivial case. Then, your database schema could look like:

```
== routes table ==
id | seats | name
---|-------|------------------
1  | 10    | simple route
2  | 30    | the scenic route

== stops table ==
id    | route_id | location | next_location
--------------------------------------------
1     | 1        | A        | B
2     | 1        | B        |
3     | 2        | A        | B
4     | 2        | B        | C
5     | 2        | C        | D
6     | 2        | D        |

== reservations table ==
// for one trip from A to B on route 1 for 5ppl
// and one trip from A to C on route 2 for 20ppl
id | route_id | start_stop_id | end_stop_id | seats_needed
------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | 1             | 2           | 5
2  | 2        | 3             | 5           | 20
```

You'll notice I've denormalized the stops table a bit by adding `next_location`, a column which doesn't necessarily add any extra information, but which will simplify our calculations going forward.

Using this schema, we can calculate -- either per-route or just per each possible leg -- the **total capacity** and the **used capacity** with this fairly simple query:

```
robert=# SELECT routes.id as route_id, stops.id as stop_id, location, next_location,
  SUM(routes.seats) as capacity,
  SUM(reservations.seats_needed) as used
FROM stops
JOIN routes ON routes.id = stops.route_id
LEFT JOIN reservations
  ON reservations.route_id = routes.id
  AND reservations.start_stop_id <= stops.id
  AND reservations.end_stop_id > stops.id
WHERE next_location IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY routes.id, stops.id
ORDER BY routes.id, location;

 route_id | stop_id | location | next_location | capacity | used
----------+---------+----------+---------------+----------+------
        1 |       1 | A        | B             |       10 |    5
        2 |       3 | A        | B             |       30 |   20
        2 |       4 | B        | C             |       30 |   20
        2 |       5 | C        | D             |       30 |
```

This table is a concise representation of your routes. We can use it to answer more complicated questions.

So suppose you want to know how many seats there are for a trip from A to D. This query will find all such seats, though it doesn't tell you what route(s) you could use to do so:

```
SELECT MIN(available) as available
FROM (
  SELECT location, next_location, SUM(routes.seats) - COALESCE(SUM(reservations.seats_needed),0) as available
  FROM stops
  JOIN routes ON routes.id = stops.route_id
  LEFT JOIN reservations
    ON reservations.route_id = routes.id
    AND reservations.start_stop_id <= stops.id
    AND reservations.end_stop_id > stops.id
  WHERE next_location IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY location, next_location
) availabilities
JOIN (
  SELECT 'A' as a, 'B' as b
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' as a, 'C' as b
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' as a, 'D' as b
) legs
  ON legs.a = location AND legs.b = next_location;

 available
-----------
        10
```

Now, this is a lot of SQL and it doesn't fully answer your question. However, what I've done is created a schema to model the directed graph of your setup, and have demonstrated a few queries on how to work with that directed graph. So yes, it is possible to do graph calculations in SQL -- but as you can see, especially with the `legs` table in the above query, it can sometimes be cumbersome. But it's by no means impossible.